# Kepler.GL: support for raster tile layer

Tags: geospatial, geojson, raster, jupyter-lab, kepler.gl

My requirement is to render both the vector data (CSV, geoJson) and the raster images (WMS or png) on the map. User would then be able to annotate such data with point or polygons. Such rendering should work as `jupyter-lab extension` and `jupyter-widget`.

I am exploring [kepler.gl](https://kepler.gl) library which meets most of the above requirements except for rendering of raster data (image, wms).

Has anyone got raster images/tiles rendering on kepler.gl? Could you please share the approach or code references?

##### PS:

I came across following information

- [open issue about raster support](https://github.com/keplergl/kepler.gl/issues/118) - there is no traction since 2020.
- [kepler-tiles](https://github.com/Zaitsev/kepler-tiles) - there is lack of documentation and does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way here is to get Mapbox reference out of your Kepler instance, and communicate with it directly: there's a `getMapBoxRef` property of a KeplerGL component available. Once you got it,

```
const getMapBoxRef = mapbox => {
  map = mapbox.getMap();
  map.on('load', () => { ... });
}
```

then you can add any of mapbox sources/layers (including images) directly to the Mapbox instance:
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/image-on-a-map/